# ICp 2.1.0.1: Installation failed with error TASK [master: Waiting for MariaDB service to start]

Tags: mariadb, etcd, ibm-cloud-private

I am installing ICp 2.1.0.1 and I received an error at the TASK

> [master: Waiting for MariaDB service to start] msg: The MariaDB
>   component failed to start.

After this msg the installation completed with failed status.
We are installing ICp with 3 Masters, 3 Proxies and 2 Workers. We have 1 IP for VIP master and 1 for VIP proxy.
I tried to install multiple times and all installations got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was solved by following the steps below.

Check whether kubelet is running:

- Log in to your master node.
- Run the following command to check kubelet status:

  systemctl status kubelet
- If kubelet is not running, run the following command to get the logs:

  journalctl -u kubelet &> kubelet.log

We found the error in the kubelet.log log:

Error: failed to run Kubelet: Running with swap on is not supported, please disable swap! or set --fail-swap-on flag to false.

We found this troubleshoot in this link, and the solution at the ICP issue 4651.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/troubleshoot/etcd_fails.html

https://github.ibm.com/IBMPrivateCloud/roadmap/issues/4651

Answer (score 0):

For prior issues with that error, the correct db admin password was not used. So check the db user and password to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would you validate whether each master host was able to access port 3306 on the other hosts?

If you run with .. `install -vv | tee -a install-log.txt`, do you get additional details as well?

Comment: Would you validate whether each master host was able to access port 3306 on the other hosts? - Yes, we disabled the firewall at the all linux server used in the installation.

We did the install using the verbose option but did not show any clear error.